# How to say "add fuel to the fire" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

The English proverb "[add fuel to the fire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/add_fuel_to_the_fire)" means "to worsen a situation or conflict, to cause it to become more intense". Similar proverbs also exist in other languages, for example in Dutch ("olie op het vuur gooien") and in German ("Öl ins Feuer gießen"). Is there a traditional way to express this proverb in Esperanto? Did Zamenhof use a similar proverb?

La angla proverbo "[add fuel to the fire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/add_fuel_to_the_fire)" signifas "plimalbonigi situacion aŭ konflikton, kaŭzi ke ĝi iĝu pli intensa". Similaj proverboj ankaŭ ekzistas en aliaj lingvoj, ekzemple en la nederlanda ("olie op het vuur gooien") kaj la germana ("Öl ins Feuer gießen"). Ĉu estas tradicia maniero por esprimi ĉi tiun proverbon en Esperanto? Ĉu Zamenhof uzis similan proverbon?

Answer (score 4):

Efektive la sama esprimo ekzistas en Esperanto, sed en la [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) estas nur du trafoj, vorte iomete variaj:

> oni ne devas verŝi oleon en la fajron [Fratoj Grimm - Elektitaj Fabeloj, trad. de Kabe]
>
> elverŝas oleon sur la fajron la fakto... [artikolo el "Monato"]

Laŭ la germana-esperanto vortaro de Krause la esprimo "verŝi oleon sur/en la fajron" estas Zamenhofa, sed ĝi ne aperas en liaj tekstoj de la Tekstaro nek en la Proverbaro, do mi ne povas tion konfirmi. Tamen la esprimo ŝajnas al mi sufiĉe bone komprenebla por esti akceptebla.

Answer (score 4):

En la hispana-esperanta vortaro de F. de Diego mi trovis sub la vorto *fajro* la jenajn samsignifajn esprimojn:

> ĵeti, (en)verŝi oleon en la fajron; blovi en abelujon; inciti abelujon

La abelujo-esprimoj ankaŭ troviĝas en Tekstaro (Proverbaro Esperanta):

> Abelujon ne incitu, amason ne spitu.
>
> En abelujon ne blovu.

En PIV troveblas la jeno:

> **enverŝi** - enverŝi oleon en la fajron [Zamenhof] (f: inciti al kverelo)
>
> **oleo** - enverŝi oleon en la fajron [Zamenhof] (eksciti ardon de disputantoj)
>
> **fajro** - verŝi oleon sur fajron [Kabe] (eksciti jam tre fortan pasion)

Comment: Mi ne konsentas, ke "inciti abelujon" estas konvena traduko de la idiomaĵo. "verŝi oleon en la farojn" signifas ja, ke oni plimalbonigas jam malbonan situacion, dum "inciti abelujon", ke oni kaŭzas senbezone situacion danĝeran por oni.
Mi jam aŭdis la formon "ĵeti oleon", sed en la Tekstaro ne estas skriba atesto por tio,

Comment: Interesa rimarko. Mi pensas ke la senco estas interpretebla. Por mi estas sufiĉe klare, ke en ambaŭ okazoj oni malplibonigas ian situacion. Multaj konsideras, ke troviĝi proksime de abelujo estas jam per si mem malbona situacio. Tamen, ŝajnas evidente kiu el la du esprimoj donas pli proksiman tradukon de la idiomaĵo.